# Локализация через ResX Resource Manager

Tags: c#, resources

В ResX Resource Manager создал переводы всех строк (Neutral,en,ru,ru-RU). Git показал, что файлы добавились. В проводнике тоже отобразились эти файлы. В обозревателе решений их нет.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru");
```

(Из App.cs)

При таких строчках должна работать локализация, но нет. 
Почему обозреватель не видит файлы ресурсов?
Почему не работает локализация?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> UPDATE:
>   Где путь `Resources` файлы отобразились. А где `Properties\Resources` не отобразились

Comment: Файлы должны быть в обозревателе решений и у них должен быть установлен пользовательский инструмент - "ResXFileCodeGenerator"

Comment: @Monk PublicResXFileCodeGenerator стоит (у Resources.resx)

Comment: Добавьте вручную русский файл в проект и ему поставьте аналогичные свойства.

Comment: @Monk Для быстроты я использовал ResX Resources Manager, чтобы избавится от такого добавления (очень затратно). Может в csproj нету этих файлов? (ru,en,ru-RU)